# CNN for behavior classification

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Based on this tutorial : https://medium.com/@harvitronix/continuous-online-video-classification-with-tensorflow-inception-and-a-raspberry-pi-785c8b1e13e1#.n7mlkeevl

They simply constructed a CRNN network by combining CNN and RNN to make a video classifier that differentiate between football game an ad on TV.

My problem is classifying or simply decide if this input video contains a cheating behavior (exam cheating) or not , so according to this tutorial , I should train the CNN by set of cheating and non-cheating images , then I would pass a sequence of frames through this network to output a sequence of (cheater / non-cheater) flags, and finally train or test the RNN with that output.

So is the CNN would performs well in that case , because I would use myself and my team to act as cheaters and non-cheaters to get a large dataset to train the CNN , that means the same person would act as cheater and non-cheater , which might result in confusion!

My final question is can I use the approach declared in the tutorial for behavior classification? .. or can the CNN successfully differentiate between cheating and non-cheating frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, using the same people for cheater and non-cheater clips will *improve* the training.  The NN will have to learn to differentiate by *action*, rather than the physical characteristics of the cheater.

I expect that this will work reasonably well for you.  However, depending on the particular behaviour, you may need to use video sequences, rather than individual frames, to describe certain behaviours.  Sometimes, cheating consists of a sequence of request and response, rather than data contained within a single frame.

Does that help?

Comment: Our approach is to pass the CNN results produced on each frame (an gathered to be a vector of cheating and non-cheating flags) to the RNN as a sequence classifier .. the same approach explained in the tutorial.

But if you don't mind , can you provide me with some techniques for video sequence classification ?!

Comment: That's beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.